# Верстка nav (кастомная кнопка)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap4

Начал изучать flexbox, и столкнулся с проблемой верстки навбара (из-за не стандартной кнопки, активного положения на скрине приложу как выглядит в дизайне).
[image: П]
Вопрос заключается в том, правильно ли я делаю, или возможно у кого то из вас есть варианты получше решения данного задания.
Что было сделано:
сверстан стандартный бутстраповский (4) nav, с классами nav-item, nav-link.
сделана кастомная кнопка активного положения (бекграунд с помощью свг, ссылка на него есть в приложенном коде).
Но часть кнопки должна вылазить с nav в низу на несколько пикселей, в таком случае, высота nav увеличивается, и текст меню, уже не центриуется по вертикали, а прижимается к верху.

Вопрос, можно ли сделать такую кнопку, что бы она выглядела так же, но не делала высоту всего nav больше, тем самым что бы текст не пришлось центрировать с помощью padding ?

```css
/*Стили Меню __ Style menu nav*/
nav.navbar.menu__box {
 padding: 0;
}
.menu__box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #00e695;
 background-image: linear-gradient(-268deg, #7800e2 0%, #9a4cfb 100%);
}
/*Стили Активной Кнопки Картинкой*/
.btn__active {
 background: url(http://mail-investbary.com/wp-content/uploads//2019/05/btn__active.svg) no-repeat;
    background-position-y: -3px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 129px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.nav-link {
 color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<nav class="navbar menu__box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn__active" href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мониторинг</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Криптовалюта</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Форум нашего блога</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Реклама</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Задай свой вопрос</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для таких случаев обычно используются псевдоклассы `::before` и `::after`. [Ваш пример с ними](https://jsfiddle.net/eyfk38dv/).

```
.btn__active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://mail-investbary.com/wp-content/uploads//2019/05/btn__active.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150%;
}
```

```css
/*Стили Меню __ Style menu nav*/

nav.navbar.menu__box {
  padding: 0;
}

.menu__box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00e695;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-268deg, #7800e2 0%, #9a4cfb 100%);
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}


/*Стили Активной Кнопки Картинкой*/

.btn__active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://mail-investbary.com/wp-content/uploads//2019/05/btn__active.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150%;
}

a.nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<nav class="navbar menu__box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn__active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Мониторинг</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Криптовалюта</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Благодарю за помощь, я что то не подумал о псевдоклассах!